# Анимация C# как вставить картинку

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть анимация движения кругов, нарисованных при помощи графикса , на c#.Как вместо круга вставить картинку ?

Comment: загрузить картинку в `Bitmap`, графикс умеет рисовать битмапы.

Comment: Вместо `DrawEllipse`/`FillEllipse` используйте `DrawImage`.